# how to remove the git unconnected versions

Tags: git, gitk

I ended up having a repository like this after reseting some branches. Now I am not sure how to clean up the repository. Can anyone explain how the hanging blue and brown line can be removed?

[image]

Comment: why would you want them removed? They are indicating that you have merged a branch into the current branch, and the commits are down below

Comment: We don't want anything above current head. we reset all branches to oct2016.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever comes here - the commits won't go because they are referenced by the tags - you must issue

```
git push --delete origin R1.10.0xxx # delete the tag on remote repo
git tag --delete R1.10.0xxx # delete the tag on local repo
```

for all the tags (yellow labels in gitk) above the Oct2016 tag